# issue in displaying visuals after creating measure in percentage

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am new to Power BI. I created two measures with two fields to be represented in percentage in chart. So I tired to pull those measures in the chart but it showed error. The tow measure that were created are:

> `IgA% = CALCULATE(Count('Ig_Ops Referrals'[IgA]), FILTER('Ig_Ops Referrals,'Ig_Ops Referrals [Site]))
>
> IgI% = CALCULATE(Count('Ig_Ops Referrals'[IgI]), FILTER('Ig_Ops Referrals','Ig_Ops Referrals'[Site_Lng_Des]))
> `

It gives the error:

[image: measure_visual_issue]

I am trying to represent two fields in percentage to created two measures for it and tried to use the chart visual, but it is not working?

Comment: Where is the value 'Allergy Partners' in your measures?

Comment: What is the visual in PowerBI? and where is the percentage calculation?

Answer (score 1):

You should use same data types columns, check if your column is both TEXT type

Answer (score 0):

[`FILTER`](https://dax.guide/filter/) usage is wrong.
The syntax is - `FILTER ( <Table>, <FilterExpression> )`, where `<FilterExpression>` should evaluate to True/False.

You are asking DAX to interpret the ***text value*** of `Ig_Ops Referrals [Site]` as ***True/False***. Those are not the same datatypes. Hence - the very clean and instructive error message.